# /usr/tmp, default path in UTL_FILE

Tags: sql, oracle, utl-file

When i am searching for directories registered to UTL_DIR i am getting the following :

```
select value from v$parameter where name='utl_file_dir';

/usr/tmp, /usr/tmp, /oradata/hrtst/db/tech_st/11.2.0/appsutil/outbound/HRTS, /usr/tmp
```

Does this mean `/usr/tmp` is the directory for `UTL_DIR` ?
also i cannot search for `/oradata/hrtst/db/tech_st/11.2.0/appsutil/outbound/HRTS` through winscp or putty.

Also i created a directory like

```
create or replace directory MY_DIR as '/usr/tmp';
```

and then i tried to write in this folder :

```
DECLARE
  fileHandler UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
begin
  fileHandler := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('MY_DIR', 'test_file.txt', 'W');
  UTL_FILE.PUTF(fileHandler, 'Writing TO a file\n');
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fileHandler);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN
     raise_application_error(-20000, 'ERROR: Invalid PATH FOR file.');
END;

anonymous block completed
```

though this block got executed succesfuly but no file got created in the directory when i checked.

[image]

Comment: `utl_file_dir` is obsolete, you should use directory objects. What do you mean with "this block got compiled succesfuly"? Was it only compiled (how?) or also executed?

Comment: directory objects are not creating new files

Comment: I use them regulary, they work as expected. Does the Linux user `oracle` have write access to `/usr/tmp`?

Comment: I have been told it does.. but is there a way to check ?

Comment: what's the output of `ls -dl /usr/tmp`?

Comment: Are you looking for `/usr/tmp/test_file.txt` on your client machine or on the server the database is running on?

Comment: @AlexPoole- I am searching for it on server through putty.

Comment: @ammoQ - i have attached the screenshot

Comment: @sreekembose - OK, what do `ls -ldL /ur/tmp` show, and  `ls -l /usr/var/tmp/*.txt` show then? (It's better to copy and paste as text rather than use images, for format as a code block). If the file isn't there then you may not be on the right server, perhaps? If it's a RAC database are you on the right node? If you didn't get an exception then the file was created *somewhere*...

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 xxhcmuser dba 0 Apr 26 17:44 /usr/tmp/myoutput.txt

This is what i am getting

Comment: since `/usr/tmp` is a symbolic link, what are the permissions of `/var/tmp` ?